# C - list of char*'s - Memory Allocation

Tags: c, memory, char

I am confused about how to allocate memory correctly. I am trying to make a list of char*'s from a text file. Every time I make a char* do I have to allocate memory for it? When and where are the exceptions?

```
#define BUFF 1000   

 int main(int argc, char** argv)
 {
  FILE* file;
    file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    char* word = calloc(BUFF, sizeof(char));
    char* sentence = calloc(BUFF, sizeof(char));
    char** list = calloc(BUFF, sizeof(char*));
    int i = 0;
while((fgets(sentence, BUFF, file)) != NULL)
{
  word = strtok(sentence, " ,/.");
  while(word != NULL)
  { 
    printf("%s\n", word);
    strcpy(list[i],  word);
    i++;
    word = strtok(NULL, " ,/.");
  } 
}
int k;
for(k = 0; k < i; k++)
{
 puts("segging here");
 printf("%s\n", list[i]);
}
```

Comment: It is #define BUFF 1000 sorry

Comment: A suggestion: call `BUFF` something like `BUFFER_SIZE` to make its meaning more explicit.

Comment: Or BUFLEN to keep it concise. However, it's not a good idea to use the same constant in all these cases ... BUFLEN, WORDLEN, SENTENCELEN, MAXWORDS are all different notions. And if you're going to use fixed size arrays, you should take pains not to overflow them.

Answer (score 3):

The rule is: you have to allocate any memory that you use.

Your problem comes in:

```
strcpy(list[i],  word);
```

`list[i]` is currently not pointing to any allocated storage (it's probably a null pointer). You have to make it point somewhere before you can copy characters into it.

One way would be:

```
list[i] = strdup(word);
```

`strdup` is not an ISO C standard function, but it is equivalent to doing `malloc` then `strcpy`. You will need to `free` afterwards.

Also, the `i++` line needs to stop when `i == BUFF`, and it'd be useful to add `\n` to the list of `strtok` separators .

Comment: Thanks matt for the response - so just to clarify: I just allocated space for the char** pointer and not the individual char*'s that it points to when I called calloc on list? So when I call calloc I am just saying that list has memory to point to individual char*'s but the char*'s themselves are not allocated? That is why I have to also allocate the individual char*s?

Comment: @user3312266 That's correct. After assigning the result of calloc to list, all the `char*`s are all 0 bits (which is NULL on many but not all implementations). You have to assign a value to them (which you aren't doing) and that value needs to be a pointer to memory somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Matt McNabb's answer, there's also a more subtle problem with your usage of `strtok`. That function doesn't require an output buffer; it just returns a pointer to somewhere inside the input buffer.

When you call `char* word = calloc(BUFF, sizeof(char));`, you allocate memory and assign `word` to point to the allocated memory. Then, when you call `word = strtok(sentence, " ,/.");`, you overwrite the value of `word`. That means that no pointer in your control points to the memory you've allocated. That memory is no longer useful to your code, and you can't deallocate it; it has been leaked.

You can fix this issue by writing `char* word = strtok(sentence, " ,/.");` Then, since you didn't allocate the memory that `word` points to, remember not to `free` it either.

Comment: But assigning a value to word, without allocating memory first, why wouldn't that cause undefined behaviour?

Comment: @user3312266 You're assigning a pointer into `sentence` (that's what `strtok` returns), which is allocated. A pointer must contain a valid address before dereferencing it, but that address doesn't have to be freshly allocated, it can be any valid address for the pointer type.

Answer (score 0):

your `list` is a char* list, with the size of `BUFF`, but the `list[i]` is what?
you do not allocate memory to it.

you need to allocate the memory for `list[i]` in a loop